# Adding up two SUM() statements as a third value

Tags: sql, sum, pjax, dataprovider

I don't know if the title is descriptive enough, but I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(col_1) AS 'value_1', 
    SUM(col_2) AS 'value_2'

WHERE ...
```

In this query I would like to add up the two values asa third column so the query would look something similar to:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(col_1) AS 'value_1', 
    SUM(col_2) AS 'value_2',
    'value_1' + 'value_2' as 'value_3'

WHERE ...
```

This query above is just illustrative, I'm aware it's incorrect, I tried this particular route.

What would be the best way to do something like this? Can it be before the `WHERE` clause or maybe somewhere else?

It's important for this to happen in the query, because the result gets passed in a Pjax data provider and must be processed beforehand.

Comment: First remove single quotes around table name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM(col_1 + col_2) AS value_3`